# Check if an array is unique (but 0 can repeat)

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$check = array(
  $_POST["list1"],
  $_POST["list2"],
  $_POST["list3"],
  $_POST["list4"],
  $_POST["list5"],
  $_POST["list6"],
  $_POST["list7"],
  $_POST["list8"],
  $_POST["list9"],
  $_POST["list10"],
);
```

I want to check if in this array all the values are unique (0 is the only value that can repeat).
So: 
1, 2, 5, 7, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1 -> wrong
1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9 -> ok
Any idea?

Comment: There are several ways. E.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php or removing the `0` and call `array_unique` and compare the arrays.... your choice.

Answer (score 1):

PHP5.3

```
$result = array_reduce ($check, function ($valid, $value) {
  static $found = array();
  if (!$valid || (($value != 0) && in_array($value, $found))) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $found[] = $value;
    return true;
  }
}, true);
```

Or

```
$counted = array_count_values($check);
unset($counted[0], $counted['0']); // Ignore "0" (dont know, if its an integer or string)
$valid = (count($counted) == array_sum($counted));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function isValidArray($array)
    {
        $found = array();

        foreach($array as $item)
        {
            $item = (int) $item;

            if($item == 0)
                continue;

            if(in_array($item, $found))
                return false;

            array_push($found, $item);
        }

        return true;
    }
?>
```